# Parsing a number into a string with boost spirit x3

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I would like to parse various numbers with spirit x3 into a string. I tried to do it like this, but it doesnt work.

```
typedef x3::rule<class int_parser_id, std::string> int_parser_type;
const int_parser_type int_parser = "int_parser";
auto const int_parser_def = x3::int32;
```

what can I do to parse a Int with the x3::int32 parser into a string?

Comment: Saying just "it doesn't work" is not telling us anything that can help you. Please describe ***how*** "it doesn't work". Do you get build errors? Crashes at runtime? Wrong results? The more details the better. If you get build errors you should copy-paste the errors (in full and complete) *as text* unedited into the body of the question. If you get unexpected results then tell us your input and the actual *and expected* output. If you get crashes then run in a debugger to locate the crash. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : In this case, it doesn't work in the same way my car doesn't swim – the library just isn't _for_ that. But if the OP knew that, they wouldn't be asking this quesiton in the first place... ;-]

Comment: This parser should parse a series of numbers into a string:  

std::string input = "1234";
std::string out;
x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), +x3::digit, x3::space, out);
assert(out == input);

(meaning 1 or more digits. The 'digit' parser's attribute is 'char' so when you put a plus in front, you get a vector of char or string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing is scanning a string in order to produce objects of a concrete type or set of types; what you're asking for is the opposite of that, which Spirit calls 'generation'. Spirit.X3 performs parsing only, so the answer to your direct question is: You can't.

However, Spirit does come with a separate component for generation: [Spirit.Karma](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/tutorials/quick_start.html).

```
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int const i = /*...*/;
std::string str;
karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), karma::int_, i);
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2bd9bbe58407a86)</kbd>

<sub>It must be noted that Karma is a C++03 codebase, and consequently has much longer compilation times than X3 – use of precompiled headers is highly recommended!</sub>